# Update sensitive code on Github and server?

Tags: django, git, github, pythonanywhere

I am new to web development and git. I have created a project which i have hosted on pythonanywhere.com. I pushed my code to github and then cloned it to pythonanywhere. I have some information in my settings.py file which i want to hide on github. So how can i make changes to the project on my local machine and update it on github and from there to pythonanywhere without revealing the hidden info.
As i said i am new to using git, so i am unaware of many tools that come with it. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solutions is:

- create `settings_local.py` near your `settings.py`
- move all sensitive stuff to `settings_local.py`
- add following code to import sensitive settings to `settings.py`:

  ```
  try:
      from .settings_local import *  # noqa
  except ImportError:
      pass
  ```
- add `settings_local.py` to `.gitignore` so git would exclude it from commits
- remove sensitive data from GitHub following [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/)
- create `settings_local.py` on pythonanywhere and your local machine manually or with some script

Comment: Thank you for your help. Exactly what i needed.